# What does the function domain with letter C stand for?

Tags: numerical-methods

I am reading a mathematics textbook on the subject of numerical analysis. In one theory the author says let us assume $f$ to be a function in $C^{n+1}[a,b]$.

I understand that $[a, b]$ is the interval limits. What I don't understand is "what the letter $C$ stand for".

It then continues to read, let $p$ be the the polynomial of degree at most $n$ that interpolates $f$ at $n+1$ distinct points.

With the above context what does $n+1$ in $C^{n+1}$ mean?

Comment: It means $f$ is a function defined on $[a, b]$ that is continuously differentiable $n+1$ times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C^n[a,b]$ is the set / space of $n$ times continuously differentiable functions on the interval $[a,b]$. Including $C^0$, the continuous functions, and $C^\infty$, the smooth functions.

Answer (score 4):

Your textbook is *Numerical Analysis: Mathematics of Scientific Computing*, correct? This notation is introduced in Chapter 1 "Mathematical Preliminaries", Section 1.1 "Basic Concepts and Taylor's Theorem", page 6 in the third edition.

Comment: Oh yes! I can see the definition there. I suspected that the author might have had defined it in previous sections, but I could not find it in first glance.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes

A (n+1) class function means that the (n+1) derivative (and all the previous ones) of the function does exist and is continuous.

Comment: Nice! thanks. I could select this as the answer too.